# Write data to file and set custom icon

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm currently developing a macOS cocoa application. Within one of the windows I'm gathering values from multiple arrays and building an xml file as a key/value backup. After saving the file I'm wanting to set a custom icon for the particular xml file. I've searched throughout stackoverflow and the rest of the web and haven't been able to find any solutions. Throughout the different functions within my application I'm able to pull a previously set icon from a file but haven't been able to set one for a newly created file. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the XML file icon you should use that:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:iconImage forFile:path options:0];
```

Where `iconImage` is a `NSImage` of the icon and `path` is the path of the xml file. Note that the change may not be visible until you rename the file or restart the computer. A workaround is renaming the xml file and then renaming it with the old name back again.

Also, note that macOS icons are different of Windows and Linux icons, so that icon may only be visible in macOS systems (in some cases, only in your machine).

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks for your time! I accepted your answer but don't have a high enough reputation for the vote to be visible.